# I am using retrofit and my output is not showing on even if there is no error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

**The output is not displayed even if there is no error and I can't seem to comprehend where I am making a mistake. It will be helpful if someone finds my error in code and help me to rectify it**

**Model class**

```
public class TopAnime {

    private Integer malId;
    private String url;

    private String title;
    private String titleEnglish;
    private String titleJapanese;


    public Integer getMalId() {
        return malId;
    }

    public void setMalId(Integer malId) {
        this.malId = malId;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitleEnglish() {
        return titleEnglish;
    }

    public void setTitleEnglish(String titleEnglish) {
        this.titleEnglish = titleEnglish;
    }

    public String getTitleJapanese() {
        return titleJapanese;
    }

    public void setTitleJapanese(String titleJapanese) {
        this.titleJapanese = titleJapanese;
    }
}
```

***ApiService Interface***

```
public interface ApiService {

    //https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime
    @GET("top/anime")
    Call<List<TopAnime>> getTopAnimeList(@Query("type") String type);
   
}
```

***RetroInstance Class***

```
public class RetroInstance {

    public static String BASE_URL="https://api.jikan.moe/v4/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static ApiService getApiService() {

        if(retrofit == null ) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }


}
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class TopAnimeAdapter   extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopAnimeAdapter.TopAnimeViewHolder>{


    private Context context;
    private List<TopAnime> topAnimeList;


    public TopAnimeAdapter(Context context, List<TopAnime> topAnimeList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.topAnimeList = topAnimeList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TopAnimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.anime_list, parent, false);
        return new TopAnimeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopAnimeViewHolder holder, int position) {


       // holder.animeTitle.setText(this.topAnimeList.get(position).getTitle().toString());

        holder.animeTitle.setText(this.topAnimeList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(this.topAnimeList != null){
            return  this.topAnimeList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class TopAnimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView animeTitle;



        public TopAnimeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            animeTitle= itemView.findViewById(R.id.animeName);
        }
    }
    }
```

**MainActivity**

*I even tried to put the findAnime() at the top thinking the error was because I was adding the 'topAniemList' into the adapter  even before the retrofit but it still gave the error*

```
 List<TopAnime> topAnimeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TopAnimeAdapter topAnimeAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView noResult;

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findAnime();

        topAnimeAdapter = new TopAnimeAdapter(this,topAnimeList);

        noResult= findViewById(R.id.noResultTv);
        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.animeRecyclerView);

        linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(topAnimeAdapter);
    }

     private void findAnime(){
        RetroInstance.getApiService().getTopAnimeList("tv").enqueue(new Callback<List<TopAnime>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TopAnime>> call, Response<List<TopAnime>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    topAnimeList.addAll(response.body());

                    noResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                else {
                    noResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TopAnime>> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: After getting response from API you are not updating adapter `topAnimeAdapter.setData(responseData)` create a method in adapter like this to update and notify changes

Answer (score 1):

**Try this - you have to pass the updated list to the adaptor and notify it**

Create the below method in the **Adapter class**

```
updateList(List<TopAnime> list){
 topAnimeList;
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call adaptor method **updateList()** from **findAnime()** method in **MainActivity.java**

```
private void findAnime(){
        RetroInstance.getApiService().getTopAnimeList("tv").enqueue(new Callback<List<TopAnime>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TopAnime>> call, Response<List<TopAnime>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    topAnimeList.addAll(response.body());
                    topAnimeAdapter.updateList(topAnimeList);
                    noResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                else {
                    noResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TopAnime>> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
```